# JMeter - Answering to pings and making a parallel request indefinitely

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a workflow to keep a user active in a site. I setup a plan for it in jmeter, but the user drops after a few minutes. The flow is:

1. https API1 get Login/token API1
2. https API2 get request for param
3. https API3 get request for param
4. Wait for Ping event (single read filter) - Here is where the
   socket connection is made.
5. Reply with a Pong (filter frame)
6. Every couple of minutes do https patch API4 using parameter from API1
7. Repeat 4 - 6 indefinitely

The problem is that API4 call is never made. The script only goes up to the websocket single read and never executes API4. I have tried the bzm parallel control, but it never executes API4 either. I considered having two different thread groups but API4 needs the token generated from API1. I have tried several other things but for the sake of simplifying my problem, I am only posting this plan. I also looked at other questions posted here and don't quite address my use case. Any suggestions are very much appreciated 
Here is the plan I am using:

[using parallel controller with websocket connection initiated inside the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA35b.png)

[creating websocket connect before entering loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGPp4.png)

Comment: When is the websocket connection set up? Does it succeed? Step 1..3 are HTTP calls i guess? You must better explain what you are doing before people can help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying Peter, yes the API calls are all https. The websocket connection is done at the single read sampler using a new connection, and it does succeed. I tried opening a websocket connection before going into the loop to avoid creating a new connection every time it loops; But the single read sampler would error out because it was unable to use the existing websocket connection. In any case both scenarios stop at the single read sampler and never execute the http api4 patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel Controller is not an answer as it will wait for `api4` prior to starting a new iteration, the only solution is to call `api4` in the separate Thread Group.

The token from `api1` can be passed via [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. I will give that a try. I originally wanted to avoid that, but it looks like that's the best thing to do.